# How to get list of all NFTs owned by a EOA in a specific collection

Tags: contract-development, nft, alchemy

I want to get all the NFTs an EOA owns in a specific collection but I found that none of the SDKs like Alchemy, Infura, etc provides this feature. So how can I do that?

Comment: Does this work? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/144048/75850